# click or select Clistctrl subitem (report view)

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

How can I determine a selected or clicked sub item of a report view Clistctrl?

Answer (score 4):

[CListCtrl::SubItemHitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxee9zz9(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: You have a sample in the link